# Is there a way to download some dataset from R in statsmodels?

Tags: python, r, statsmodels

I know that some of the datasets in R packages can be accessed using this technique

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
dataset_iris = sm.datasets.get_rdataset(dataname='iris', package='datasets')
```

I am looking to download following car insurance dataset:

```
library(insuranceData)
data(dataCar)
```

Is there a way to download the data?

## Attempts

```py
#df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('dataCar').data
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset(dataname='dataCar', package='insuranceData')
ValueError: Dataset dataCar was not found.
```

Comment: Have you considered rpy2?

Comment: I am totally noob to R and here I am simply trying to get the dataset. I have not tried rpy2. If I had rpy2, it would be trivial and we can use both r and python in same jupyter notebook. Here I am only looking a way to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jupyter notebook you can use wget to get the data, the use pandas to read the data.

```py
!wget http://www.businessandeconomics.mq.edu.au/__data/assets/file/0011/232310/car.csv

df = pd.read_csv("car.csv")
df.head()
```